# Visual Studio C# Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to learn Unit Testing in C#.  But I don't see how to relate the testmethods to the actual methods.  In one guide it told me to right click the method name and click create unit test.  I don't see that.  Another told me to create a  Unit Test Project in the solution and add my other project to the references.  I still don't see how to reference a specific method or class to test in the testing project.

I see how it works, just not how to "target" the methods and classes I want to test.  Since I can't instantiate them, I don't know what else to do.  I try to instantiate because of protection level, but the class is public.  I know I shouldn't change the namespace on the unit testing project's test class, but I don't know what else to do.

I keep reading tutorials and nothing seems to work the way they say.

Please give me a simple explanation and short example for C# unit testing.

For example 2 projects, one has namespace BankCS and class BankAccount, the other is UnitTest1 namespace and class BankAccountTest.  In BankAccountTest when I try to instatiate bankaccount inside BankAccountTest I get `BankCS.BankAccount.BankAccount() is inaccessible due to its protection level`

From this line of code: `var ba = new BankCS.BankACcount()`

Tried changing the namespace to be the same as the project I am testing and it made no difference.

EDIT:

I got the errors fixed but am still getting System.Object is defined in an aseembly that is not referenced.  You  must add a reference to assembly System.Runtime....

Not sure how to do this, don't see it anywhere.

Also I understand unit tests I use them in Python a lot.  But using them in Visual Studio and C# is a lot different.  Which is why I would appreciated a short example.  Also, why did the one tutorial say to right click the method and click create unit test, I've never seen that option just Run Tests and Debug Tests.

Seems my issue is, being able to instantiate what I want to test in my Unit Test Project, any tips for doing this?  Any gotchas?

Comment: Inside your test project, add a reference to the "real" project. Right click references -> Add reference -> Projects -> Solution -> Check your "real" project.

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: There's nothing special about referencing a project from a unit test project.  Do you know how to add project references in Visual Studio at all?  What are the exact things you're doing and how exactly is it failing?  If you add a project reference to the code you want to test then you can execute that code.  This is true of any references in .NET.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @David I added the project reference to the unit test project.  This is why I want a short example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> BankCS.BankAccount.BankAccount() is inaccessible due to its protection level

If the constructor isn't public then you can't access it from outside the class.  This is true of all C# code (and pretty much object oriented code in general), nothing to do with unit tests.

If you want to create a new instance of an object, that object needs a public constructor:

```
public BankAccount()
{
    // constructor logic
}
```

Note that C# creates a public, parameterless constructor by default for all objects *unless* you provide a constructor.  So if you're providing a non-public one:

```
private BankAccount() { /.../ }
```

then there won't be a default public one.

Comment: This is not the best solution better is using `PrivateObject.GetFieldOrProperty()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243729.aspx

Comment: @fsacer: I don't see what's better about that.  It seems to be using reflection, which means you don't get compile-time type safety.

Comment: @fsacer: I would argue that defining one's objects effectively and understanding how one would use and test those objects is a better solution than just giving up on the design and relying on reflection.  There's a reason statically-typed languages are statically-typed.

Comment: You shouldn't make a public constructor just for unit tests -- that affects your public API in an important way. Either use PrivateObject or make it internal and use [InternalsVisibleTo(string)].

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Nor should you try to construct an object that doesn't have a public constructor.  The tests should test visible functionality.  If none of the visible functionality *uses* the non-visible functionality then the non-visible functionality can safely be removed, rendering the point moot.  Workarounds like `InternalsVisibleTo` create brittle coupling between the code being tested and the tests.

Comment: @recursive My point was that you shouldn't make a public constructor just for unit tests.

Comment: @fsacer:  Fair enough, but if there's no public way to create an instance of your class, then I don't think there's a good justification for testing it at all.

Answer (score 1):

A unit test in its most simplistic sense is meant to test your code before your deploy it by use of automated testing capabilities rather than manually running through a test of your code strictly as a user. A good easily understandable overview of setting up a unit test for C# can be found here;

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/391465/Creating-Unit-tests-for-your-csharp-code
Also try looking through github for a unit test you can easily implement.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the method or class you are trying to access is not public.  Is it private, protected, or internal?  If so, change the class and method to public.  Another option is to use the [`InternalVisibleToAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so your tests can access classes/methods that are marked as internal.

Comment: [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include more of the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.